# Included css from controller doesn't apply on page

Tags: css, symfony, controller, include

I'm actually trying to set in my twig template css generated from a controller. File is included (if I access the url of the controller in my browser I see generated css) but not applied.

For more details, I've got a twig template (`base.html.twig`) in which I include controller result using `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ path('mycsscontroller') }}">`.
The `'mycsscontroller'` route go to `MyCssController:indexAction`which return `$this->render('mytwigfile.css.twig')`.
The content generated is a valid css.

I already tried to set generated content in a file then include it using `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('mycssfile') }}">` and css is included and applied on page!

I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong there...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try return response in you controller with css content type

> return new Response('my_css_styles_as_string', 200, ['Content-Type'
>   => 'text/css'])

Comment: I just thought about it before i went eating, still didn't tried but I'm pretty sure that's the tip.
Thx